I want a formal mathematical definition of the configuration space of a system (mathematically defined examples appreciated)
The Wikipedia article on configuration space offers this "formal definition":

In classical mechanics, the configuration of a system refers to the position of all constituent point particles of the system.[2]

A quick look at the source (Structure and Interpretation
of Classical Mechanics, Sussman, page 9) gave no helpful definition either. Please help me and give a tight mathematical definition of what is meant by a configuration space, with whatever function and point--set related terminology is needed.

A physical point particle takes positions in a subset of $\mathbb R^3,.$ What more do you need to make that definition formal enough?

Is the configuration space a point or the collection of all points that a particle can occupy? IF particle $i$ can occupy all space in the closed disk $\mathbf D^2$, THEN is the configuration space ${ (x_i , y_i) \mid x_i^2 + y_i^2 \le 1 } $ ? For a system of particles, does this become collection $ \left { { \forall (x_i , y_i) } \right }_i$?  Would we use $t = i$ as an index w.r.t. time? Would we define it as another coordinate point in a Galilean system? Both (conditionally)? Things like this is why I would like a tighter definition/example, so that there's no hand waving.

Have you considered a google search for configuration spaces? There are plenty of lecture notes, talks, etc.
The main point with your collection of particles is the constraint that no two particles can occupy the SAME point at the same time. That's why the configuration space isn't quite the closed disc if you have more than one particle.

I cannot believe that in the literature you consulted the configuration space of $n$ particles isn't introduced as the $n$-fold Cartesian product of their individual configuration spaces.

Remember that physics and math are different things. One must be careful not to get carried away by pure mathematical arguments when analyzing the mathematical structure of physical concepts. Especially, one must realize that there are no purely mathematical definitions of physical objects and concepts. The configuration space is a deeply physical concept.
At face value, there isn't much to it mathematically: If one assigns a coordinate to all physical parameters of a system, then the configuration space is the set of all points so that the combination of their coordinates is physically allowed. Of course, if one adds constraints to the system in the form of a system of equations, the configuration space takes on some more interesting structure; the symplectic manifolds of classical mechanics are a good example of this. However this structure depends directly on the mathematical structure of the theory and the constraints imposed on it, and any rigorous definition of configuration space for a specific theory must be based on those. Without a given theory, the configurarion space is not really a mathematical object in itself other than "the set of physically allowed states" which is not exactly well-defined.
